# Data annotations on models when there are multiple repository implementations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

My DTOs are pretty simple classes.

```
public class PlainClass {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<PlainSubClass> SubObjects { get; set; }
}

public class PlainSubClass {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a repository interface, whose implementations are meant to retrieve data.

```
public interface IRepository
{
  IEnumerable<PlainClass> PlainObjects { get; }
}
```

Now, I want to implement that interface in another class mocking the database and also using EF SQLite, and possibly more in the future. My mock is simple but, in trying to implement and then generate the database I'm getting an error back stating I need to designate a primary key.

Now, how should I go about doing that? Should I build out interfaces for my models and add annotations specific to each implementation? Should I -- if it's even possible -- add multiple sets of annotations to the models?

Comment: You can add multiple attributes, that's the route I would go. The whole point of repo is to abstract away your db provider. If you start to add models for specific providers, then your code upstream will have to change when working with a different provider.

Comment: But by adding data annotations specific to a provider in the model, is it not defeating at least part of the purpose of abstracting away the DB provider?